# How to update bulk of items in a FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript

This below **UpdateLocationIndex** function is not working as expected.

```
UpdateLocationIndex(updateStartingIndex: number)
{
   for (let i = updateStartingIndex, l = this.MyControls().length - 1; i < l; ++i) 
   {
       this.MyControls().at(i).patchValue({
            LocationIndex: this.MyControls().at(i).get('LocationIndex').value-1
         })
   }   
}

 public MyControls(): FormArray {
    return this.formData.get("ControlList") as FormArray
  }
```

Say there are 100 items in the array, if i want to update the Location Index of last 20 items , i call the function as UpdateLocationIndex(80)

Comment: can you share more debugging info ? what happens when UpdateLocationIndex is called ?

Comment: That is the start point of the loop. Say there are 100 items in the array, if i want to update the Location Index of last 20  items , i call the function as UpdateLocationIndex(80)

Comment: `for (let i = updateStartingIndex,i < this.MyControls().length; i++) ` BTW, if you use this when you delete an item, I suggest that your FormArray has no "indexLocation" else, when submit add the property using some like `const result=this.MyControls.value.forEach((x,index)=>{x.indexLocation=index})`